# Lockless unsafe data sharing bus in rust

Tags: rust

I am relatively new to rust, and I want to use `Arc<>` to give immutable access to some data to many threads, however I want to be able for the original owner of that `Arc` to have write access without introducing any kind of lock (mutex, rwlock etc). My application guarantees that there is only ever a single thread producing (writing) to the data inside the arc (so never a write data race to the arc). But there are many threads reading the data in the arc. (reading, not consuming). How do I implement this? Whenever I go near `Arc` and try to mutate I am not allowed to. Obviously I understand unsafe is needed for this.

The bus is created and cloned over to the reader threads.

```rs
use std::borrow::BorrowMut;
use std::sync::Arc;

type Data<T> = Arc<Vec<T>>;

pub struct Bus<T> {
    data: Data<T>
}

impl<T: Clone + Send + Sync + 'static> Bus<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let data: Data<T> = Arc::new(Vec::new());
        
        {
            let mut data = data.clone();
            std::thread::spawn(move || {
                let a = data.borrow_mut();
                a.push(value); // write to vector
            }).join();
        }

        Bus {
            data
        }
    }

    pub fn read(&self, idx: usize) -> T {
        self.data[idx].clone()
    }
}
```

gives:

> cannot borrow data in an `Arc` as mutable

Comment: What if `Vec` needs to grow after write and deallocates the value which is being read at that time by another thread? That's an UB, too.

Comment: @Cerberus hmm, then If I use some not continuous data structure like hashmap?

Comment: It will need to reallocate on growth, too. The only structure which might work is something like linked list, and only if you manually guarantee that it won't ever drop or move the already-allocated items.

Comment: @t348575 Even still -- hashtables need to grow when they reach about 75% bucket usage. It really doesn't matter the structure, though. Every structure offers a way to clear it out, which drops all values. What you're asking for isn't memory safe and it's exactly the kind of thing Rust is designed to prevent.

Comment: @cdhowie What if I just used a fixed size slice? All I need is some sort of buffer to send data out to all the consumers.

Comment: @t348575 Is there a reason you can't just use channels with Arc-wrapped data values? What problem are you trying to solve here that channels wouldn't be a solution for?

Comment: @cdhowie I have thousands of consumers for each producer. Creating a 1:1 channel for each consumer and sending it over to the producer seems wasteful. (Consumers are clients connecting to my server) moreover only client A should receive messages intended for it, and using a channel for many consumers cannot be done because then it will be receiving messages meant for another client, which also seems wasteful.

Comment: @t348575 You can have both -- a fanout channel for broadcasts and 1:1 channels for consumer-specific messages. Overall this sounds like a message broker might be a good solution, which could also enable horizontal scaling of your consumers.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer - Concurrent data structures are hard and I'm not an expert in them

---

The error message you get is essentially saying "you can't mutate the contents of an `Arc`, because other people could be reading it while you change it, causing a data race.

The typical solution is to use an `Arc<Mutex<T>>`. A `Mutex` allows you to go from an immutable reference to a mutable reference by first locking the mutex.

However, you've indicated you don't want to use locking.

So if `Mutex` (and similar things like `RwLock` are off the table, you'll need a `Vec`-like data structure that allows mutation via immutable reference.

However, my understanding is there's generally very little reason to prefer a "concurrent" or "lock free" `Vec` over a simple `Arc<Mutex<Vec<T>>` (or probably an `Arc<RwLock<T>>` in your case). In general, the performance will be similar.

[This reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/pbg2fm/concurrent_vector_library_in_rust/) has some insight into why such data structures don't really exist if you want some further reading.

There are also concurrent `HashMap`-like structures if you find that model is also suitable. Maps are generally more amenable to this kind of lock-free or highly concurrent workload.

For example, `chashmap` uses per-bin locking (i.e. each bin in the map has its own lock), so lock contention stays relatively low.

There is also `evmap` which is entirely lock-free, but comes at the cost of being only eventually consistent and using ~2x the memory. It essentially maintains 2 copies of your map, one of which is a "read map" and the other is a "write map". You can then "publish" the changes to apply the writes.

Comment: The problem is I have many many consumers (maybe thousands) for each producer, so the moment I use any lock won't the performance drop massively? Like the graph shown on the [evmap github](https://github.com/jonhoo/evmap)

Comment: `evmap` does not do locking. If I understand your question correctly, there is only ever a single thread writing. The graphs you link show read throughput against number of readers, and with a single writer the performance scales roughly linearly (which is pretty much the best case you can hope for). Also in the `chashmap` case, the locks are per-bin, meaning a write to the key `"foo"` won't lock the key `"bar"`, which can drastically lower contention in many applications

Answer (score 0):

No, if a `Vec<T>` is written by one thread and read by multiple threads, here is a data race.

There are some other lock-free options, but they all different from your example.

- If `T` is a simple type (a common integer type or a type with appropriate length and `Copy` trait implemented) and the `Vec` length is fixed, you can use a fixed-length array + atomic type. You can safely read and write each element, but cannot grow the array.

  Crate [`atomic`](https://crates.io/crates/atomic) provides a `Atomic<T>` type and you can check if it is lock-free at compile time.
- AFAIK, a lock-free `Vec` is not possible, however some crates offer lock-free queues. But obviously a queue cannot be accessed by an index.